# PHP mysql code not executing

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to make a website, and by my 'create new student' page i tried to use some MySQL code generated from phpmyadmin, when i inserted a new test row. But when i execute this code it doesn't insert it into my database.

**connection.php**

```
<?php

define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "root");
define("DB_NAME", "spelling");

$connection = new mysqli(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    exit("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());};
?>
```

**addstudent.php**

```
<?php session_start();
require_once("connection.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
    Add a student
    </title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="addstudent.php" method="post">
        Full Name:
        <input type="text" name="fullname" autocomplete="off">
        <br />
        Username: 
        <input type="text" name="username" autocomplete="off">
        <br />
        Password:  
        <input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off">
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Add Student" name="submit">
        </form>
<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"]) ){
    $_POST = array_map("strip_tags",$_POST);
    $_POST = array_map("trim",$_POST);

    $fullname = $_POST["fullname"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $query = "INSERT INTO `spelling`.`students` (`SID`, `fullname`, `CID`, `username`, `password`) VALUES (NULL, '".$fullname."', '1', '".$username."', '".$password."')";
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don’t execute the query.

Comment: So where's the query executed? Writing a query string doesn't means that you perform a query.

Comment: Besides that, your code is vulnerable to SQL injections; you should read on [how to prevent them in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Comment: Read a manual. They are for it.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to run your query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `spelling`.`students` (`SID`, `fullname`, `CID`, `username`, `password`) VALUES (NULL, '".$fullname."', '1', '".$username."', '".$password."')";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

Or checking for errors at the same time.

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

Also remove the stray `;` in

```
exit("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());}; // <=
```

change it to

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    exit("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
```

Comment: My code still doesnt add the student to the database, so where could the problem be?

Comment: Check `mysqli_error()` to see what MySQL reports is wrong

Comment: @marcnetz Reload the answer. There was a slight error in the variables' placement.

Comment: @mickmackusa hammered!